# Commenting in matlab

Tags: matlab, comments

This sounds like a simple question. I have the following snippet:

```
target=strcat(string, ...
              string2, ...
              'suffix' );
```

A simple string concatenation written in multi-line. There are times I have to comment out intermediate text i.e. `string2` with `%`. However doing this gives an error message: `parse error at ')': usage might be invalid matlab syntax`. Can someone help me on commenting out the middle line with alternative forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line continuation command `...` makes everything after it a comment, and (of course) makes MATLAB continue with the next line. So to comment out `string2` in your function call, use `...` instead of `%` to comment out.

With `string2`:

```
target=strcat(string, ...
              string2, ...
              'suffix' );
```

Without `string2`:

```
target=strcat(string, ...
              ... string2, ...
              'suffix' );
```

Answer (score 3):

To comment out part of a statement that spans multiple lines, use an ellipsis (...) instead of a percent sign. For example,

```
target=strcat(string, ...
         ... string2, ...
          'suffix' );
```